# How to access data outside the Alamofire block using swift 3.0

Tags: ios, json, swift3, alamofire

I've just started 'Alamofire' for JSON parsing. Now I'm facing some problem which are as follow:

**Problem Statement :** Unable to access data outside the Alamofire block.

**Coding Stuff :**

```
import UIKit

import Alamofire

    class ViewController: UIViewController
    {
        var dataValue = String()
        override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            Alamofire.request("url") .responseJSON 
            { response in

                dataValue = response.result.value
                print(dataValue) // It prints value
            }
            print(dataValue) //It does not print any thing or nil.
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hint: Look for `completionHandler:`

Comment: please provide me some example, for completion handler, because I'm new to it.

Comment: @Ashish it doesn't have completion part, please check my answer

Comment: Ashish, IDT those answer will serve your actual purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var dataValue = String()
 override func viewDidLoad()
 {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   Alamofire.request("url") .responseJSON 
  { response in

     dataValue = response.result.value
     self.myFunction(str: dataValue)
  }
  }

 func myFunction(str: String)
 {
    print("str value ====%@",str)
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, now I got it. How to access data outside Alamofire.

Comment: Hello, it parse JSON data and update UIView very slowly. Why does this happens?

Answer (score 3):

Alamofire block is an asynchronous callback. In other words, it will run the completion block whenever the response is ready.
If you would like to use the `dataValue` whenever it is set. You can take advantage of `didSet` in variable properties.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var dataValue = String() {
       didSet {
           // do something here
           print(dataValue) // It prints value 
       }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Alamofire.request("url") .responseJSON 
        { response in

            dataValue = response.result.value
            print(dataValue) // It prints value 
        }
        print(dataValue) //It does not print any thing or nil.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire uses block for getting web API's So as according to your problem . You can check by putting break points into block and after block.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
    {
        var dataValue = String()
        override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            Alamofire.request("url") .responseJSON 
            { response in

                dataValue = response.result.value
                print(dataValue) // It prints value
            }
            print(dataValue) //It does not print any thing or nil.
        }

    }
```

That line doesn't print anything because it will debug first, while your alamofire block debugs and returns when you get response & it will print value.

So I think you can use value of dataValue into another functions as it stores after getting response into block.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Jecky for your answer.

Comment: You are right, variable outside the Alamofire debug first, then Alamofire, that's why it prints nil.